# WPF - How to hide a button on ChildWindow when I call it from MainWindow using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have two WPF forms (`MainWindow` and `ChildWindow`) with their different viewModels already in place (`MainViewModel` and `ChildViewModel`) to manage the events.

When I click the menu item on `MainWindow` to open the `ChildWindow`, I want a specific button to be hidden in the `ChildWindow`.

How can I perform this using MVVM?

Comment: Please post your code / xaml

Comment: How are you open the `ChildWindow` and from where? You could for example pass a `bool` or something to its constructor that tells it whether to hide the `Button` by returning this `bool` from a public property that you bind to in the view.

Comment: I'd follow the execution chain: menu click -> Command -> Viewmodel method - etc.. until I am within viewmodel for child window (constructor call?). Then it's all about adding parameter/property.

Comment: As far as extending something without breaking it, I would recommend looking into an `event aggregator` like the `PubSubEvent<T>` in the PRISM library, MVVM light or equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the child window's VM

1. Put a Boolean property (with the change notification as with other properties on the VM) which when true will show the button and false hide it.
2. On the button's `Visibility` property bind to the VM property and use a Boolean to visibility converter (has one already been defined in the page's resource, of so use it) to take the true/false value and change it to a visibility value.

---

This article doesn't get into the full blown history of MVVM, but it provides a basic example to help you with MVVM and binding:

[Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017)